# API in comparison with a full application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

We have a classic **Rails** application that we are willing to convert into an **API** only back-end. A **Javascript** framework will replace the **UI** portion.

At its current state, the *classic* application is fully based on **AJAX** calls, so the end user can feel that it's using a full **JS Framework**, but in reality it's just **jQuery**.

In comparison with the classic application, how the newly updated application ( **API** with **JS UI** ) will behave. I know that the server will not have to compile and serve views anymore, wich is a gain, but how much gain will I have, we are talking here about performance. Is it worth the hassle?

Comment: Was my answer useful?? consider select it as accepted answer, regards...

Comment: Im still waiting for you to mark my answer as accepted, I spent some time answering you...

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time mate. I will not accept your answer, first because it's not what I was looking for, second, accepting it means no one will find interest in answering my question again.

Answer (score 0):

Use Rails as an API and have the front and backend in different applications won't have significant difference in your current performance.

Performance is something very abstract and can be improved from many point of views. your rails backend won't have to serve views, however your JS UI will have to communicate with it through the API what in performance matter means the same.

For improve your performance you need to have an optimized backend and also an optimized front-end, it does not matter if you have separate apps for serve backend and the frontend.

Check This [blog post](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/a-new-way-to-understand-your-rails-apps-performance/) that will drive you about the rails performance. Also for those who want to convert their current apps in just backend from rails take a look to [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api), It's basically a stripped down version of Rails (you don't need things like cookie authentication or MSIE rendering helpers in an api server).

**Summary**: Maximize your performance as a developer. Use stack you know best. First make it work, then make it fast, it does not matter if you separate front end from backend.